# How to use gatsby-source-wordpress and add ACF to Menu's, Menu items and query with GraphQL

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

Is it possible to query ACF added to Menu's and Menu Items? 
I was struggling with this specific use case of querying data in Gatsby app enhanced with gatsby-source-wordpress plugin and query a Wordpress used as a CMS paired with ACF to enhance menus and menu items,  the below queries are not working for menu related queries but acf is recognised for custom post type "Hero":(can retrieve menu data other then acf )

[image]

Would be glad if someone could advise on this issue.

in plugin config enabled endpoints:

```
includedRoutes: [
          "**/categories",
          "**/posts",
          "**/pages",
          "**/media",
          "**/tags",
          "**/taxonomies",
          "**/users",
          "**/*/*/menus", // <== Menu api endpoint
          "**/*/*/menu-locations", // <== Menu api endpoint
          "**/*/*/hero", // <== hero api endpoint
        ]
```

active plugins:

[image]

Tnx

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-to-rest-api/

Comment: Hi Ksav, yes I am using the "ACF to REST API", "WP REST API Menus" ..